# Translate site in own text-language

Tags: customization, language, text

I have content in two language for my website(English and Arabic) .I want to translate website in these my two custom content language rather then any language translator.  Please tell me how can i translate my site in these two language only.
I mean website is showing in English by default but when i choose Arabic language like any language translator, its showing my own Arabic language on my website.
Please help me asap.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a translation plugin - I can recommend the two the [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) and [qTranslate X](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/).

The main difference is that the Polylang creates separate language version posts for a specific page, the qTranslate-X keeps all the language versions in the same post's fields using its specific markup. The Polylang is actively updated, qTranslate-X has its hard time lately so you can have problems implementing it with some latest more complicated plugins like for instance Yoast SEO.

It depends what you like and what you need - check them both and see for yourself.

Comment: I want to translate website in my two custom content language rather then any language translator. When i click on arabic button want to show my own arabic content for the whole website instead of  chaning their default arabic language.

Comment: So when you'll do the translation yourself for the content in the Wordpress backend using one of the plugins, you will get on the front a switch for changing language, and when clicked it will display the site, with your translation in the language of your choice.

Comment: May be want to create sub site for Arabic content. Is this only solution?

Comment: It could be an alternative - instead of using plugins to make Wordpress site multi-language you can set up two copies - one in English and one for Arabic content.

Comment: Ok. thanx for the suggestion and your valuable time.

Comment: Is here any plugin which can translate English to Arabic language.I'm using https://wordpress.org/plugins/gtranslate/ but is doesnt translate properly. I mean some words are not translate through it.I want to translate every words respectively.